# What is the location of files (WAR and JAR) pushed to Nexus 3 from Maven

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I am using **Nexus Repository 3** as storage for my build files. More precisely **WAR** and **JAR** artefacts which are deployed to repository via Maven deploy plugin.

I have been searching in multiple folders under `/sonatype-work/nexus3/` but I  couldn't find any files.

Where exactly (file path) is Nexus storing WAR and JAR files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Nexus Repository 3 the files are stored in blobs as described here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-BlobStores

You will not find the physical files in your storage like you did in Nexus Repository 2.  The database has references to the blobs and does all the work under the covers to retrieve them from your build tools and UI when called.

Comment: So will  it work if we do a  "Wget" from nexus location to download the files

Comment: @gibyalex You can wget (or curl, etc) using the same URLs the UI or REST provide.  Hope that also helps the question edit 1 year later (which I obviously didn't cover in my year earlier answer).  The specific path to downloading files is depending on your server name and context path so cannot be given generically.